Inheritance in Java and its confusing things
class A {
    public void m() {
        System.out.println("A.m");
    }
    public void n() {
        System.out.println("A.n");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    @Override
    public void n() {
        System.out.println("B.n");
    }
    
    public void p() {
        System.out.println("B.p");
    }
}

class C extends A {
    @Override
    public void m() {
        System.out.println("C.m");
    }
}

class D extends C {
    @Override
    public void m() {
        System.out.println("D.m");
    }
    @Override
    public void n() {
        System.out.println("D.n");
    }
    
    public void p() {
        System.out.println("D.p");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new D();
        a.m();
    }
}

Why is the statement A a = new D(); not reported by the compiler when class A is not directly the superclass of class D?
Please someone explain to me the difference between Object type and Reference type.

Why do you think A a = new D(); should be an error?

why should it be? it still extends A through it's direct parent class. Nothing confusing about it

D is_a C and C is_a A. Consequently, D also is_a A. It's as simple as that.
Subclasses defined by extends are transitive (and also interfaces implemented with implements apply to all subclasses). If this weren't the case, you couldn't do things such as:
final Object obj = new ArrayList<>();
// ArrayList extends AbstractList extends AbstractCollection extends Object
final AbstractCollection<Object> coll = new ArrayList<>();
final AbstractList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

